# How do i use a progressBar to perform an progress for each process in my program?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

In the top of the form i did:

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
progressBar1.Minimum = 1;
```

Then in the button click event that start the operation i did:

```
timer2.Enabled = true;
if (this.backgroundWorker1.IsBusy == false)
            {
                this.backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
```

Then in the backgroundworkerdowork event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            if (filesContent.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < filesContent.Length; i++)
                {
                    File.Copy(filesContent[i], Path.Combine(contentDirectory, Path.GetFileName(filesContent[i])), true);
                }
            }
            DoProgressBar(e, worker);
            WindowsUpdate();
            CreateDriversList();
            GetHostsFile();
            Processes();
        }
```

All the functions in the DoWork event are copying files the Processes() function use a new class i did that use Process to create/copy files.

Then the new DoProgressBar event function i did:

```
private static void DoProgressBar(DoWorkEventArgs e, BackgroundWorker worker)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 90; i++)
            {
                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                    worker.ReportProgress(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

Then ProgressChanged event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

Then the completed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.Cancelled == true))
            {
                this.label1.Text = "Canceled!";
            }
            else if (!(e.Error == null))
            {
                this.label1.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
            }
            else
            {
                this.progressBar1.Value = this.progressBar1.Maximum;
                processfinish = true;
            }
        }
```

Timer2 tick event:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerCount += 1;
            TimerCount.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timerCount).ToString();
            TimerCount.Visible = true;
            if (processfinish == true)
            {
                timer2.Enabled = false;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
            }                           
        }
```

And timer1 tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            Diagnose.Text = "PROCESS HAS FINISHED" + "  " + countBack--;
            if (count == 6)
            {
                Diagnose.Text = "COLLECT INFORMATION";
                Diagnose.Enabled = true;
                CreateZip.Enabled = true;
                ViewLogFile.Enabled = true;
                DriverVerifier.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                TimerCount.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

I know its a long code but everything here is connected.

What i wanted to do is that the progressBar will get progress according to the progress of each function in the DoWork event .

But instead what is it doing now is first going to the :

DoProgressBar() event/function do the second/else part ReportProgress(i)

Then its going to the Progresschanged event and do:  progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;

The result is when i click the button click to start the opertion i see right away the progress bar moving almost to the end instead moving according to each function/progress of the program.

You can see my complete code of Form1 here:

```
http://codepaste.net/fuk9w5
```

EDIT:

This is the code of the class ProcessRun where im using in Form1 in the function Processes()

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen
{
    class ProcessRun
    {


        public void ProcessesRun()
        {

        }

        public static void Processing(string WorkingDirectory, string FileName, string Arguments, bool StandardOutput, string OutputFileName)
        {
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = StandardOutput;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = FileName;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments;
            proc.Start();
            if (StandardOutput == true)
            {
                string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                DumpOutput(WorkingDirectory + "\\" + OutputFileName, output);
            }
            proc.WaitForExit();
            proc.Close();
        }

        private static void DumpOutput(string filename, string output)
        {
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(filename);
            w.Write(output);
            w.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can see all my Form1 complete code here: http://codepaste.net/fuk9w5

Comment: Grant i just tried it again now i marked the timer2.enabled = true; with // so it wont be in use so it wont actiavte start the timer2 tick event . And i still see the progressBar running fast to the right almost to the end. When you copied the code what did you use or did with the function Processes() ?

Comment: Grant yes with the code above. The progressBar is running to the right fast almost to the end. I tried now to remove the timer2.enabled = true; in the button click event diagnose start button click event and still i see the progressBar running almost to the end.

Comment: Grant i just updated my question added there the class i did called ProcessRun which im using the function in there in Form1 inside the function Processes()

Comment: Grant i gave a link in my question to my full Form1 code. Try it with the link above with the full Form1 code and the class ProcessRun i just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your background thread is interacting directly with a UI element (the progress bar). That's a problem. Your background thread can't directly interact with the UI element; it has to invoke it such that the UI update occurs on the UI thread.

You could, for example, add a method like this to your form:

```
// Form method for updating progress bar; callable from worker thread
public void UpdateProgressBar(double progress)
{
    // dispatch the update onto the form's thread
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<double>)((n) =>
    {
        // do the update in the form's thread
        progressBar1.Value = n;
    }), progress);
}
```

You can then call this method from your worker thread and the progress bar should update properly.

Comment: Oops... that's the WPF way... for WinForms should be Invoke not Dispatcher.BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 0):

why not put this into your code? This is how I move the "green" part of the progressbar.

```
progressBar1.Step = pos; //where pos is the number on how much do you want to increase the progress of the progressbar
progressBar1.PerformStep(); //triggers the movement of the progressBar.
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who ended up here while trying to find a way to change value of progess bar with cross threading this is how you do it:

```
form.Invoke((Action)delegate { form.function(); });
```